# How do I move data from from an api to statehook?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, fetch-api, react-hooks

I've run into this issue more than once and I could use some advice.  I have an api call.  I want to display the results in another component that is a child of the form.  I've worked out a component that can map state to jsx but I'm having trouble understanding the part where I actually use the new Array from my API response. I have a function that makes this call from a seperate module.

```
const data = []  
const search = (values, loadData) => {

fetch(`/search`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
    body: values
})
    .then(checkStatus)
    .then(parseJSON)
    .then(res => {
               let items = res.response.docs

                for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                    console.log(items[i].start)

                    data.push({
                        headline: items[i].title,
                        web_url: items[i].web_url,
                        snippet: items[i].snippet

                    })
                }
                console.log(data)
            }

          )
}
const fetcher ={search, otherthings}
export default fetcher
```

I want to have a set of methods that I can call that keeps things modular,  But I am kind of hazy when it comes to mapping the api response to state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display the results in a child of the form you want to do something like this where the search results are set in the form component state and passed down to the component which displays them.

I've simplified the request function to remove a lot of code which just changes a single property name of the docs list and mocked it for the example.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

// our search function which will return a promise that resolves to docs
const search = values =>
  // fetch(`/search`, {
  //   method: 'POST',
  //   headers: headers,
  //   body: values
  // })
  //   .then(checkStatus)
  //   .then(parseJSON)
  //   .then(res => res.response.docs);
  Promise.resolve([{ id: 1, name: "doc 1" }, { id: 2, name: "doc 2" }])

// our component to render the results
const Results = ({ docs }) => docs.map(doc => <div key={doc.id}>{doc.name}</div>);

// our Search component with the form that passes results to it's child
const Search = () => {
  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);

  // call setResults with the value returned by `search`
  const doSearch = e => search({ query: e.currentTarget.value }).then(setResults);

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <input onChange={doSearch} />
      </form>
      <div>
        <Results docs={results} />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

see working example here.. https://codesandbox.io/s/5zrx67k94

Just type a char in the input to trigger the request.

To display the results in **any** other component you'd want to use either a central data store such as Redux, or use React Context. For the latter you could move the state that holds the results, and the search function into a Context Component and export the function and results, use it from your form to make the call and set the state, and use it from your other component to access the state. You'd also need to render the context provider in the component tree above both components.

Maybe start with the simple solution above for now.

Comment: I've implemented your suggestions.  I also put all of my code into the same file which broke things, but thats just because functionResults wants values to feed .map() but doesn't have any results until the api does its thing. This solution is kind of how I tried to solve this problem the first time I came up against it.  I was looking into Redux and Context as potential solutions, are they the only to make things modular?

Comment: it's only one aspect, but yes, Redux or Context (fyi Redux uses Context) let you avoid passing props down through multiple layers of components by allowing you to move the state out of any particular component and access it from many components. This also gives you the ability set state from child components lower in the tree and access it from components higher in the tree which you can't do by passing props *down*.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  React looks like it, but then I also keep seeing the useReducer, context, and Suspense.  Is React kind of simplfying the things that Redux does?

Comment: mm, not entirely. `useReducer` is a better option to `useState` for dealing with a larger state object, but it's still for local, not global, state. `useContext` lets you share state with multiple components, and you can combine it with `useReducer` for a simplistic Redux alternative, but there are performance issues which means you wouldn't want to use a single instance for all of your app state as all components would update on every change. And you don't get redux dev tools, which are awsome.